# Who is responsible for calling CoInitialize and CoUninitialize if surrogate process or COM+

Tags: com, atl, com+, isapi

Who is responsible for calling CoInitialize and CoUninitialize if

1- I host a COM dll within a surrogate process (either by using dcomcnfg utility or COM+ wizard)?

2- I build a ISAPI DLL that contains COM objects?

Answer (score 0):

No idea on case 2, but in case 1 the surrogate process certainly calls `CoInitialize()`/`CoUninitialize()`. Here's how I know this.

We have a COM object that we host in COM+ and that itself uses MS XML 4. When you need to create an XML document object in MS XML 4 you call `CoCreateInstance()`. We never call `CoInitialize()` in our COM object, yet document creation is always successful - certainly the surrogate calls `CoInitialize()`. If we do the same in a stand-alone app document creation fails unless we ourself call `CoInitialize()`.

So the bottom line is: COM+ surrogate (and I'm sure that applies to DCOM surrogate as well) calls `CoInitialize()` itself.

Btw you can use this to investigate the case 2 - call `CoCreateInstance()` inside the ISAPI dll - if it is successful `CoInitialize()` has already been called.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you have any idea whether COM+ surrogate joins a STA or MTA?

Comment: @arnold: Looks like it depends on the COM object treading model: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681753(VS.85).aspx